# Ember create a polymorphic record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, polymorphism, ember-data

I am trying to create a record for a model that has a polymorphic relationship.

Here is the model:

```
App.SupportedTransportationMethod = DS.Model.extend({
  resource: DS.belongsTo('resource', { polymorphic: true }),
  transportationMethod: DS.belongsTo('transportationMethod')
});
```

And the model I'm trying to create the record with:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  supportedTransportationMethods: DS.hasMany('supportedTransportationMethod', { async: true }),
  companyName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And here I am trying to create a record:

```
supportedTransportationMethod = this.store.createRecord('supportedTransportationMethod', {
  transportationMethod: transportationMethod,
  resource: contact
});
```

But I get an assertion error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'resource' record to this relationship
```

I have a jsbin showing this. If you click one of the checkboxes then you'll get the error. I am trying to create the record down in the CheckboxItemController.

http://jsbin.com/qebis/6/

Any ideas how I am to accomplish this? I looked at [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547584/how-do-i-set-an-ember-data-polymorphic-model-in-qunit) but that doesn't fly well with dynamically creating where you have no idea what the id will be. Nor does pushing feel right.

UPDATE:

If I use the ember-data prod version, it allows the creation (because the assertion is code is removed from the prod version). So I'm wondering if this is a bug in the assertion code?

```
Ember.assert("You can only add a '" + type + "' record to this relationship", !value || value instanceof typeClass);
```

It does however create it with the type set to the current model type even if it is extending from a base model. Not sure yet if that is a good thing or not...

UPDATE 2:

Here is another jsbin to show the effects of the previous update. http://jsbin.com/qebis/7/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Data expects the records to be inherited from the same base class. In your case you're specifying `resource` but it doesn't seem like you have defined it as a `DS.Model`.

You should have something like:

```
App.Resource = DS.Model.extend();

App.Contact = App.Resource.extend({
  supportedTransportationMethods: DS.hasMany('supportedTransportationMethod', { async: true }),
  companyName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: Ahah, I see my error. I must have looked at your gist https://gist.github.com/Cyril-sf/515085e856f9dac2f06a a thousand times and never noticed you were inheriting from the base class. duh me.... it now works! http://jsbin.com/qebis/10/ Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

For those using `ember-cli`, note that that `MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true` prevents model inheritance form working for polymorphic relationships as of `Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.11`.

See https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2065

Comment: this works for `ED#.0.0-beta.12` or lesser versions. Fixed in `beta.14`